# Circular moving average on a tuple in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, average, moving-average

Given a tuple `v = (1,2,3,4,)` how do I transform it to a tuple of rolling averages, accounting for circular endpoint calculations, i.e. The output is

```
((4+1+2)/3, (1+2+3)/3, (2+3+4)/3, (3+4+1)/3,)
```

Naturally, the vector and window sizes can change. In the example above bandwidth is 1 (window size 3).

Comment: if window size is 2, what the output should be? ((4+1)/2, (1+2)/2, (2+3)/2, (3+4)/2,) or ((1+2)/2, (2+3)/2, (3+4)/2, (4+1)/2,)

Comment: window here (and usually) is defined as 2*bandwidth + 1. If bandwidth is an natural number, then window size is always odd :) Thanks! Good clarification question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just stick the extra elements onto the end of the list:

```
def movingAverages(seq, k):
    circle = seq + seq[:k]
    for j in range(len(seq)):
        yield sum(circle[j:j+k])/k
```

For example:

```
list(movingAverages([1,2,3,4,5],2))
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.0]
```